# What is "VESA standard" PCB mounting pattern

Tags: connector, lvds

In hirose's [LVDS connector datasheet](https://www.hirose.com/zh/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=FX15&documenttype=Catalog&lang=zh&documentid=D49372_en), I find there is a "PCB mounting pattern : VESA standard", but I can't find out what is special for this mounting pattern. May someone give some clues.

Thanks.

Comment: Enhanced Shielding

Comment: Are you sure? Please confirm this. In the datasheet, receptacles with enhanced shields have both VESA standard version and NON-VESA standard version.